# Converting a hexadecimal string into binary in Objective-C

Tags: php, objective-c, cocoa

What's an equivalent of the PHP function `pack`:

```
pack('H*', '01234567989abcdef' );
```

in Objective-C?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7194528/465378

Comment: possible duplicate: [How to convert hex to binary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194528/how-to-convert-hex-to-binary-iphone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want the results as an NSData, you can use a function similar to this:

```
NSData *CreateDataWithHexString(NSString *inputString)
{
    NSUInteger inLength = [inputString length];

    unichar *inCharacters = alloca(sizeof(unichar) * inLength);
    [inputString getCharacters:inCharacters range:NSMakeRange(0, inLength)];

    UInt8 *outBytes = malloc(sizeof(UInt8) * ((inLength / 2) + 1));

    NSInteger i, o = 0;
    UInt8 outByte = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < inLength; i++) {
        UInt8 c = inCharacters[i];
        SInt8 value = -1;

        if      (c >= '0' && c <= '9') value =      (c - '0');
        else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') value = 10 + (c - 'A');
        else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') value = 10 + (c - 'a');            

        if (value >= 0) {
            if (i % 2 == 1) {
                outBytes[o++] = (outByte << 4) | value;
                outByte = 0;
            } else if (i == (inLength - 1)) {
                outBytes[o++] = value << 4;
            } else {
                outByte = value;
            }

        } else {
            if (o != 0) break;
        }        
    }

    return [[NSData alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:outBytes length:o freeWhenDone:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works. There is nothing doing that in the Cocoa libraries already?

Comment: Also it looks like you're leaking `inCharacters`

Comment: inCharacters is allocated using alloca, which allocates space on the stack rather than the heap.  If you are dealing with large strings and don't feel comfortable advancing the stack pointer that far, you probably want to change inCharacters to a malloc() and free() it before the return.

Comment: Oops, didn't see your first reply.  It depends on your use case - If the hex value is short enough that you can store it an unsigned int or unsigned long long, there is -[NSScanner scanHexLongLong:].  If you need to do additional extraction, you could use the wscanf() family on -[NSString characters]

Comment: oops sorry for alloca() of course that makes sense. Looks like your solution works well.

Comment: @iccir can you translate this in Swift please.

Comment: No, sorry.  I haven't touched Swift yet.

Comment: This will not work for hex strings with odd-numbers. You need to change the else clause to
            {
                outByte = value;
                if ( i == inLength - 1 ) // this is going to be the last iteration
                {
                    outBytes[o++] = outByte << 4;
                }
            }
otherwise you're missing data.

Answer (score 1):

See the `-scanHex...` methods of `NSScanner`.