# NSData to NSString and vise versa

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, aes, nsdata

My user is prompted to enter in RAW NSData (like: <0201581d 9fc84f7b bf136a80 e7fc9572>)

This raw data is an AES encrypted NSString.

However, the issue is converting those actual bytes of data <0201581d 9fc84f7b bf136a80 e7fc9572> into an NSData type itself.

1. Prompted to enter data
2. Enters data --> @"<0201581d 9fc84f7b bf136a80 e7fc9572>"
3. Needs to make entered data into an NSData type rather than the NSString which was passed.

In short; How do I make this: <0201581d 9fc84f7b bf136a80 e7fc9572> into the NSData's data?
Making an integer hold the data HALF works (because the type is too short) so It needs to be an NSString.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is extremely similar to [NSString (hex) to bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501033/nsstring-hex-to-bytes). The answer there will work for you if you remove the excess punctuation.

Comment: I used a combination of this and iccir's solution. I needed the hex string to use this solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To convert a hexadecimal string to data, see the function that I posted here:
[Converting a hexadecimal string into binary in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950644/converting-a-hexadecimal-string-into-binary-in-objective-c/8950667#8950667)

You will want to modify it slightly to allow bracket characters and whitespace.

To go the other direction:

```
NSString *CreateHexStringWithData(NSData *data)
{
    NSUInteger inLength = [data length];
    unichar *outCharacters = malloc(sizeof(unichar) * (inLength * 2));

    UInt8 *inBytes = (UInt8 *)[data bytes];
    static const char lookup[] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };

    NSUInteger i, o = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < inLength; i++) {
        UInt8 inByte = inBytes[i];
        outCharacters[o++] = lookup[(inByte & 0xF0) >> 4];
        outCharacters[o++] = lookup[(inByte & 0x0F)];
    }

    return [[NSString alloc] initWithCharactersNoCopy:outCharacters length:o freeWhenDone:YES];
}
```

You can also use:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", data]
```

to use -[NSData description] to get a version with the brackets and spaces.

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for unfortunately. The NSData is encrypted so it's not an actual NSString. I just need to store it to a type.

Comment: I used your conversion, but it's useless without the string converted into actual NSData. Upvoted; But Rob gets the acceptance

Answer (score 0):

To convert NSData to NSString use :

```
NSData* returnData;
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

To convert NSString to NSData use :

```
NSString* str = @"returnString";
NSData* data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```