# How do I set the bits in a byte?

Tags: objective-c, nsdata

I need to store a series of 1s and 0s of arbitrary length.

I had planned to use ints, but then it occurred to me that really all I need is a bitstream.

NSMutableData seems like just the thing. Except all I see anyone talking about is how to set bytes on it, or store jpegs or strings in it. I need to get way more granular than that.

Given a series of 1s and 0s such as: 110010101011110110, how do I make it into an NSData object--and how do I get it out?

NSData's appendBytes:length: and mutableBytes are all at the byte level, and I need to start lower. Storing those 1s and 0s as bytes doesn't make sense, when the bytes themselves are made of sets of 1s and 0s. I'm having trouble finding anything telling me how to set bits.

Here's some faux code:

```
NSString *sequence = @"01001010000010"; //(or int sequence, or whatever)
for (...){//iterate through whatever it is--this isn't what I need help with
     if ([sequence intOrCharOrWhateverAtIndex: index] == 0) {
          //do something to set a bit -- this is what I need help with
     } else {
          //set the bit the other way -- again, this is what I need help with 
     }
}
NSData *data = [NSData something]; //wrap it up and save it -- help here too
```

Comment: `how do I make it into an NSData object--and how do I get it out?` two choices: treat each 0 and 1 as a byte you append to the NSData (and waste a lot of space), or write your own subclass that keeps track of the number of valid bits in order to pack them together and provide access as appropriate for your needs.

Comment: @mah-...right, so the second one there: how do I do that?

Comment: um… brute force? What part of it isn't clear how to do? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutabledata_Class/Reference/NSMutableData.html has several methods which I'm sure you'll want to use, such as appendBytes:length: and mutableBytes

Comment: @mah- Apparently this is child's play to you, so much that you can't even conceive that I don't understand it. It would be pleasant if you stopped expressing bewilderment at my lack of comprehension. I've read that link plenty, and I've come here because I don't see how to do what I want from that. If you would like to share the things that are obvious to you, this might be the kind of forum in which such gestures would be meaningful.

Comment: If you're not willing to read the docs, try something, reach a failure point and then ask for help about the new problem you're having, then you're asking for someone to write your code for you -- something that goes against the purpose of stack overflow. I pointed you at a significant class and the two significant methods of that class to get you started. I would be happy to write your code once we reach a contractual (read: payment) agreement.

Comment: @mah-apparently the kind of help I need strikes you as too low-level to be appropriate for Stack Overflow. That's fair. You see it as pointless to comment further. You may be right. There's not much point in debating it. Cheers.

Comment: Perhaps you should read http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and learn about what is appropriate, with emphasis on the _constructive_ section. Furthermore it's worth pointing out that among the canned valid reasons for closing posts is _Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it_ and _Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results._

Comment: For what it's worth, I suspect most of the hostility is around everyone focusing on "how do I make an NSData from this" when the actual sticking point ends up being "how do I set individual bits in a byte". The answer to the former is "read the docs". The answer to the latter is "bit shifting plus addition".

Comment: @mah-as Catfish says. Twice now you've assigned me things to read. If I may return the favor, please read his very helpful answer, it's a model of civility.

Comment: And for what it's worth, let me own my part: I did not express myself as clearly as I might have, and I expressed myself in an abrasive manner, which I regret, and for which I apologize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you literally have 1s and 0s? Like... ASCII numerals? I would use NSString to store that. If by 1s and 0s you mean a bunch of bits, then just divide the number of bits by 8 to get the number of bytes and make an NSData of the bytes.

(Editing to add untested code to convert a bitstream to a buffer)

```
//Assuming the presence of an array of 1s and 0s stored as some numeric type, called bits, and the number of bits in the array stored in a variable called bitsLength
NSMutableData *buffer = [NSMutableData data];
for (int i = 0; i < bitsLength; i += 8) {
    char byte = 0;
    for (int bit = 0; bit < 8 && i + bit < bitsLength; bit++) {
        if (bits[i + bit] > 0) {
            byte += (1 << bit);
        }
    }
    [buffer appendBytes:&byte length:1];
}
```

Comment: ....yes, Catfish_Man, what you are advising me to do is what I am asking how to do. Given a number or string 0100010101110, how do I turn it into bytes and store it in NSData.

Comment: Those have very different answers though! Which do you want (number or string)?

Comment: They have different answers? I know how to inspect both a number and a string. That's not the question. The question comes once I've written a loop to inspect the sequence of 1s and 0s. Yes, the inspection is different, but I don't need help with that. I need help with understanding, at each iteration, what I do with the results of the inspection.

Comment: it's tantalizing, because the way you say it, it sounds really easy to do, and I've spent hours looking at docs and stuff and I don't get it. If it's so simple, please tell me! How do I take a series of 8 ones and zeros and make a byte out of them?

Comment: Added untested code to take an array of bits and append them byte by byte to an NSMutableData

Comment: (What do you have that's giving you lists of bits though? That seems highly unusual)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41234/discussion-between-le-mot-juiced-and-catfish-man)

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer from: [Convert Binary to Decimal in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618403/convert-binary-to-decimal-in-objective-c)

Basically, I think the question could be phrased, "how do I parse a string representation of a binary number into a primitive number type". The magic is all in strtol.

```
  NSString* b = @"01001010000010";  
  long v = strtol([b UTF8String], NULL, 2);
  long data[1];
  data[0] = v;
  NSData* d = [NSData dataWithBytes:data length:sizeof(data)];
  [d writeToFile:@"test.txt" atomically:YES];
```

Using this idea, you could split your string into 64 character chunks and convert them to longs.

Comment: Thanks for the info--but my question must be so poorly written that it seems like I'm asking something totally different. I should edit it, but honestly it's been so long I don't really want to wade back in. At any rate, I wasn't looking to convert between number types, or numbers and strings, or anything like that. I was looking for how to set individual bits in a byte. Anything higher than bit-level inspection was not of concern. Again, though, I appreciate your helpfulness.

Comment: I see. Did someone point you toward the bitwise operators? Using masks and or union and interesect you can set any bit in a byte. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/objective_c_bitwise_operators.htm